# Smooth Camera Controles like in Subway Surfer Game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am implementing a game like subway surfer but in game i have turns also. So my question is how to follow a player with such smoothness like in subway surfer game?

```
Transform mTransform;

Vector3 currentPos;

Quaternion rot;

public static float XOffSet = 0.2f;

private void LateUpdate()
{

       float targetX = -playerScript.targetXOffset * 0.2f;
        offsetPosition.x = Mathf.Lerp(offsetPosition.x, targetX, xDamping * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector3 wantedPos = player_.TransformPoint(offsetPosition);

        wantedPos.y = Mathf.Lerp(mTransform.position.y, wantedPos.y, playerScript.camHeightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

        mTransform.position = wantedPos;

        Quaternion rot_ = Quaternion.Slerp(mTransform.localRotation, player_.localRotation, Time.deltaTime * xDamping);

        mTransform.localRotation = rot_;

        mTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(14, mTransform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);  

}
```

The above code is working absolutely fine but am feeling it's not smooth while following; it is feeling somewhat jerky. How can I improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Use Tweening plugin, like DOTween "its free",you can do something very simple just like this:

```
Mainplayer.Transform.DOMoveY(float value, float time);
```

with this example , it will move the player along Y axis with certain value through the given amount of time. Same for any other axis

```
Mainplayer.Transform.DOMoveX(float value, float time);
Mainplayer.Transform.DoMoveZ(float value, float time);
```

Not just like this, even for rotation you can do DORotateX...etc and too may felxable functions that help you to lerp player or any object from point to point

To be more correct, Tweening meant to lerp between two values whatever they are as long as they are supported, from vectors, floats, colors...etc